# Book's author in opengraph data not used?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My website contains information about books and it contains open graph data. Things seem to mostly work. I've set og:title to the name of the book. For people I could find, or pages about them, I add url to that page in book:author. But nothing seems to happen with the author information, and I can't see a  way (for a normal user) to see who the author of the book is.  Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your question... what are you really want do?

Comment: Use the linter. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I already tried the linter before.  On one example it shows me:
book:author: Array of length 1
⍾ 108349532523848

https://graph.facebook.com/108349532523848 properly shows that this is about Tatiana de Rosnay.

People "like" the page, and it shows up under their interests, but nowhere does it mention Tatiana de Rosnay, only the name of the book.


Kurt

Comment: Similarly, if a linked to the page is posted, only the title of the book shows up, not the author.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you just use like the books, author information is not show up anywhere. 
But you can make any FB  opengraph action, and in that case you can see the author's name in the wall post , or in the aggregations.

But be careful , the FB documantion is a  little bit tricky :

```
<meta property="book:author" content="Who wrote this">
```

However, content MUST be an URL, not the author name here and author page og needs to contain an og:profile tag .